# from clustering to portfolio selection in R

Tags: r

I need help.
I need to make a portfolio selection (Markowitz) and my script is the following:

The following is the matrix of stock returns:

```
a <- c(0.00444, -0.00553, -0.01007, -0.00012, 0.04133, -0.02472, -0.01771, 
   -0.00994, -0.06933, 0.00476)
b <- c(-0.01926, 0.06008, 0.02839, 0.00930, 0.02072, 0.02072, 0.03670, -0.02049, 
   -0.01644, 0.02375)
c <- c(-0.00719, 0.02296, -0.06438, 0.008805, -0.00603, -0.00663, -0.01160,
   -0.00298, 0.00713, 0.00790)
d <- c(-0.01753, 0.00809, 0.02301, -0.00631, -0.026114,0.03157, -0.02488, 
   -0.01013, -0.03231, -0.00763)
e <- c(-0.02153, 0.00863, -0.02929, -0.01424, -0.01940, -0.02313, -0.04146, 
   -0.02610, 0.00050, -0.04700)
stocks <- cbind(a,b,c,d,e)
```

And the following is the market index:

```
rmkt <- c(-0.01159, -0.02787, -0.05936, -0.09417, -0.03027,-0.03161, -0.03166, 
   -0.04092, -0.02841, -0.009781)
```

for example the time is 10 so:

```
time <- 1:10
```

I used the following code for clustering:

```
Nsim = 10
opt_num_centers = rep(0, Nsim)
est_centers_coefs = est_centers_fits = rep(list(0), Nsim)
for(kk in 1:Nsim){
 rmkt_list <- list()
 for(i in 1:5){
      rmkt_list[[i]] = rmkt  
   }
   stock_list_mat = do.call("cbind", stocks_list)
   class(stock_list_mat)
   stock_mat <-  stock_list_mat[, c(1:societies_stocks)]
   class(stock_mat)
   nseg = 30
   B = basis_array(time, min(time), max(time), ndt = nseg, 
               deg = 3, max_derivs = 0, sparse = FALSE) [[1]]
   M <- ncol(B)
   P <- crossprod(diff(diag(ncol(B)), diff = 3)) 
   dim(stock_mat)
   class(stock_mat)
   est_coef = matrix(0, nrow = M, ncol(stock_mat)) 
   est_bet = matrix(0, nrow = nrow(stock_mat), ncol(stock_mat)) 
   dim(est_coef)
   dim(est_bet)
   smooth_par = NULL
   for(i in 1:ncol(stock_mat)){
    bb = expectreg.ls(stock_mat[ , i] ~ rb(time,"special", by = rmkt, B = B, P = P),    
                        smooth = "schall", expectiles = 0.5)
  
      smooth_par = c(smooth_par, bb$lambda$time)
      est_coef[, i] =  bb$coefficients$time[, 1]
      est_bet[, i] = B %*% bb$coefficients$time[, 1]
       }
   sc_est_coef = scale(est_coef)
   aa = (clusGap(t(sc_est_coef), kmeans, 10, B = 100, nstart = 50, iter.max = 50))
   n_clust = maxSE(aa$Tab[, "gap"], aa$Tab[, "SE.sim"] ,"Tibs2001SEmax")
   opt_num_centers[kk] = n_clust
   km = kmeans(t(sc_est_coef), n_clust, nstart = 100, iter.max = 100)
   est_centers_coefs[[kk]] = t(km$centers)
   est_centers_fits[[kk]] = B %*% est_centers_coefs[[kk]]
   cat("\t", "simulation =", kk, "\n","\t", "# Clust =", opt_num_centers[kk], "\n")
}
```

Considering everything how can I proceed to make a portfolio selection?

Thank u all.

Comment: This does not appear to be a question about programming.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, probably more than is necessary to answer the question, and no explanation for it. What are you trying to do exactly? What does the code do? Where are you stuck with it? Remember the *minimal* part of the [mcve] guidance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.